# iptables : ! not allowed with multiple source

Tags: iptables, firewall, ubuntu-18.04

When I run this command :

`sudo iptables -I FORWARD '!' -s x.x.x.x,y.y.y.y -d 172.18.0.3 -p tcp --dport 9114 -j DROP`

I get the error :

iptables v1.6.1: ! not allowed with multiple source or destination IP addresses

Any ideas what is the correct command for this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negated logic should work here:

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -d 172.18.0.3 -p tcp --dport 9114 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -s x.x.x.x,y.y.y.y -d 172.18.0.3 -p tcp --dport 9114 -j ACCEPT
```

Commands have to be entered in this order so that the `DROP` rule appears last in the chain.

Comment: thank you
this worked for me